# bypass cross origin frame in websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

hi i'm really stucked in this challenge from root-me, so i need to take advantage of the xss found  in    $("#chatbox").append("You: "+$("#input").val().replace('<','').replace('>','')+"\n") using an iframe but i don't know how to do that because of cross origin frame. I think that i have to use iframe.contentWindow.postMessage() to target the the event listener " input.keydown " but i'm not sure about that because i didn't found anything that could help me to do that. Sorry for my english not my native language

```
$(function () {
    var input = $('#input');
    window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
    if (!window.WebSocket) {
        alert('Sorry, but your browser doesn\'t support WebSocket.')
        window.location.href="/"
        return;
    }
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+'/ws');  
    connection.onopen = function () {};  
    connection.onerror = function (error) {
      alert("An error occured, you will reload the page for you to access a new room !")
      location.reload()
    };
    connection.onmessage = function (message) {
      $("#chatbox").append("You: "+$("#input").val().replace('<','').replace('>','')+"\n")
      $("#chatbox").append("\nBot: "+message["data"].replace('<','').replace('>','')+"\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n")
      $('#chatbox').scrollTop($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight);
      $("#input").val("")
    };
    connection.onclose = function(message) {
      $('#chatbox').append("--------------------------END OF COMMUNICATION--------------------------")
    }
    input.keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var msg = $("#input").val();
        if (!msg) {
          return;
        }
        connection.send(msg);
      }
    });  
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

so i created an iframe from my page like you see above

```
 <body>
        <p id="para"></p></body>
        <script>
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = 'http://ctf02.root-me.org/room';
        iframe.height = '90%';
        iframe.width = '90%';
        iframe.onload = actions;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);
        function actions(){
            setTimeout(function() { get_cookie();}, 5000);
            }
        
        function get_cookie(){
            
            }
        </script>
```

and the website inside the iframe is using this code to display the input value and the websocket server response in the #chatbox :

```
$(function () {
    var input = $('#input');
    window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
    if (!window.WebSocket) {
        alert('Sorry, but your browser doesn\'t support WebSocket.')
        window.location.href="/"
        return;
    }
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+'/ws');  
    connection.onopen = function () {};  
    connection.onerror = function (error) {
      alert("An error occured, you will reload the page for you to access a new room !")
      location.reload()
    };
    connection.onmessage = function (message) {
      $("#chatbox").append("You: "+$("#input").val().replace('<','').replace('>','')+"\n")
      $("#chatbox").append("\nBot: "+message["data"].replace('<','').replace('>','')+"\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n")
      $('#chatbox').scrollTop($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight);
      $("#input").val("")
    };
    connection.onclose = function(message) {
      $('#chatbox').append("--------------------------END OF COMMUNICATION--------------------------")
    }
    input.keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var msg = $("#input").val();
        if (!msg) {
          return;
        }
        connection.send(msg);
      }
    });  
});
```

so i want to modify the value of the #input and send keydown from my page